# Calling constructors from constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

In this code I present below I am having a problem. It manifests as a bad_alloc exception, and this is because the argument passed to `reader`, the `CompressedBufferReader`, is a bad string.

```
class FileReader { 
    FILE *file; 
protected:
    unsigned char *data; // local copy
    long size;
public:
    FileReader(const char *filename);
    ~FileReader();
    unsigned long getSize();
    unsigned char *getFileData();
};

class CompressedBufferReader {
    unsigned char *buffer;
    unsigned long len;
public:
    CompressedBufferReader(unsigned char *);
    ~CompressedBufferReader();
    unsigned char *getBuffer();
    unsigned long getLength();
};
CompressedBufferReader::CompressedBufferReader(unsigned char *srcCompressed) {
    len = 0; buffer = 0;
    len = GetDecompressedBufferSize(srcCompressed);
    buffer = new unsigned char[len]; if (!buffer) throw std::runtime_error("Cannot allocate!");
    WriteDecompressedBuffer(buffer, len, srcCompressed);
}
CompressedBufferReader::~CompressedBufferReader() {
    delete[] buffer;
}
unsigned char *CompressedBufferReader::getBuffer() {return buffer;}
unsigned long CompressedBufferReader::getLength() {return len;}

// similar interface to FileReader. Does not inherit because it does not benefit from doing so.
class CompressedFileReader {
    CompressedBufferReader reader;
public:
    CompressedFileReader(const char *filename);
    unsigned char *getFileData();
    unsigned long getSize();
};

CompressedFileReader::CompressedFileReader(const char *filename) : reader(FileReader(filename).getFileData()){} // this line is causing the problem
unsigned char *CompressedFileReader::getFileData() { return reader.getBuffer(); }
unsigned long CompressedFileReader::getSize() { return reader.getLength(); }
```

To be more specific, it seems like the FileReader which I create anonymously becomes deallocated before its data contents can be passed to the constructor of `reader`, a `CompressedBufferReader`.

the problem is that I cannot write `CompressedFileReader`'s constructor in a way that allows me to properly instantiate a `FileReader`, because I intend to use `CompressedBufferReader`'s constructor and that means I must call it before the body of the constructor. Bit of a catch-22. How is this issue resolved?

Comment: I think it's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the implementation of `FileReader`. But as a general remark, your code is very "manual" and would probably be a lot simpler to read and maintain if you used standard containers and strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem in the way you use the constructors, which should cause the bad_alloc (though the code does seem clumsy). Let us look at the execution of the line that is causing the problem -

```
CompressedFileReader::CompressedFileReader(const char *filename) : 
   reader(FileReader(filename).getFileData()){}
```

The following steps take place:

1. A temporal `FileReader` is created. Its constructor is called with `filename`, which is a `const char*`.
2. The constructor does unknown things, because we don't have its code. It should, I assume, read the file into an allocated buffer, stored at the `data` member of the `FileReader`.
3. `getFileData()` is called on the temp `FileReader`, returning the value of `data`, I assume, which is an `unsigned char *`.
4. `reader`, which is a `CompressedBufferReader`, is constructed using the `unsigned char *`.
5. The temporal `FileReader` is destructed.

So, the problem is not with the order of the constructions, or the lifespan of the temporary `FileReader`. There are a few unknown which you should look into:

1. Does the constructor of `FileReader` create a valid buffer, and stores it in `data`?
2. Does `getFileData()` return the buffer created?
3. Does `GetDecompressedBufferSize()` return the correct value for a valid buffer?
4. Does the exception happen to be thrown from `WriteDecompressedBuffer`, whose code we don't have?

Lastly, you might want to simplify your code. Constructions like that aren't very readable. And, of course, the use of standard container like vectors would make it safer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to step through this. Yes for 1 and 2, as for 3: that function reads out a value from the buffer itself. 4: The exception happens because `GetDecompressedBufferSize` returned a bad (huge) value. It's because `CompressedBufferReader` ctor got an incorrect argument. I'm trying to figure out why the right buffer didn't get sent there.

Comment: I found the culprit. It was actually bad pointer arithmetic. It did occur within the `GetDecompressedBufferSize` function.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is violating a very important rule, known as the "big three"

> If your class has **any** of a destructor, assignment operator or copy
>   constructor then it should have **all three of them**.

The reason is that if a custom destructor is present then most probably the automatically synthesized assignment operator and copy constructor (that are simply member-by-member copy constructions or assignments) are not going to be the right thing to do.

This rule is so important that if you happen to find a case in which it's meaningful to have for example a destructor but the default copy constructor then just write at least in a comment that you didn't forget about copy constructor and/or assignment but that the automatically provided one are going to be correct.

If instead your classes must not be copied or copy constructed then forbid the operation by declaring it private and by not writing the implementation.

In your specific case when an instance of either of your two classes gets copied or assigned the pointer will be copied but then the data will be destroyed twice.

Comment: Read the code again. `reader` is not constructed with a `FileReader` - the full code is: `reader(FileReader(filename).getFileData())`, note the `getFileData()` part. The fact that you've missed that tells something about the readability of the code, of course, but no copy construction is being done here. `reader` is initialized with an `unsigned char *`.

Comment: It's a shame ... you can mark favourite questions, but not favourite answers.

Comment: @eran: true. I removed that part. This code still stinks pretty bad (for example why using all those explicitly badly managed buffers instead of using for example `std::vector<unsigned char>`?). Also that with this kind of code how can you be sure that nothing bad happened before with the typical UB evolution (i.e. nothing apparently happens, and the problem explodes only one million instructions executed later in an innocent place) ?

Comment: The answer still incorrectly claims that the problem is copy-ctoring from a temporary, which is not the case.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: The answer is not talking about the temporary any more and the phrase "In your specific case when an instance of either of your two classes gets copied or assigned the pointer will be copied but then the data will be destroyed twice" is correct. Also how can you know that bad ownership management is not the problem given that the code is not complete?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I did neglect to consider this issue.

Comment: @6502 is this sufficient to force a class to disallow invokation of the copy ctor or assignment operator? `ClassName(const Classname&);
ClassName& operator=(const ClassName&);` Putting them inside the declaration of course. I wonder if there is a way to do this generally so I could for instance make a class inherit `NonCopyable` to auto disable them.

Comment: @Steven Lu: Yes. The standard approach is to just declare them private and to not give the definition: being them private if any user code calls those operation you'll get a compile error... and being them not defined if any class method or friend invokes copy construction or assignment by mistake you will get a link time error. This is also what boost does (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/noncopyable.hpp )... even if probably using boost for just this is nonsense.